# Displaying related field from table into a datatable issue

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable

I am trying to display a related field in a datatable. But, it will not let me access said field.

Example: I have a modal called Level. I have another called Classes. 
A Level can have many classes, but a class can only belong to one level.

Here is the Level model:

```
public function classes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\NiixClass');
}
```

And the Class model

```
public function level()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Level');
}
```

When i try and access the Level->name nothing is returned. 
For example from this:

```
$classes = NiixClass::select(['classes.id', 'classes.name', 'classes.created_at', 'classes.updated_at'])->with('level')->get();
dd($classes[0]->level()->get());
```

I get:

```
Collection {#413
    #items: []
}
```

Update:

```
dd($classes[0]->level);
```

This returns null.

Update 2:

Here is the Class schema

```
public function up()
{
    //
    Schema::create('classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('level_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('thin_background_image_local');
        $table->string('thin_background_image_s3', 2083);
        $table->string('full_background_image_local');
        $table->string('full_background_image_s3', 2083);
        $table->boolean('is_free')->default(false);
        $table->integer('num_minutes');
        $table->integer('sort_order');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

Here is the Level schema

```
public function up()
{
    //
    Schema::create('levels', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('training_programme_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('logo_image_local');
        $table->string('logo_image_s3', 2083);
        $table->string('background_image_local');
        $table->string('background_image_s3', 2083);
        $table->integer('weeks_num');
        $table->text('description_intro');
        $table->text('description_main');
        $table->string('video_local');
        $table->string('video_s3', 2083);
        $table->integer('sort_order');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

Comment: Can we see the database schemas? You need to either name the foreign key in the classes table according to convention or specify the field name in the Level model.

Comment: I have updated the question with the schemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a select already (without related field) filters out the result the query returns to the limited fields you supplied (and excludes the relation), i.e:

```
NiixClass::select(['classes.id', 'classes.name', 'classes.created_at', 'classes.updated_at'])->with('level')->get();
```

You should remove the select function, and see what you have, i,e:

```
 $classes = NiixClass::with('level')->get();
 dd($classes->first()->level); //level is a nested object in the collection
```

**Update**:

In order to still limit the result to some fields in the classes table, you need to include the foreign key, i.e 'level_id' amongst your select:

```
$classes = NiixClass::select(['id', 'name', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'level_id'])
           ->with('level')
           ->get();
```

Doing this, the related table could then be called because the related field is included.